# Cannot make `compile-command` buffer local

Tags: compilation, compile

I've tried making `compile-command` buffer-local via

```
(defun compilation-make-locals (process)
  (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
       compile-command))
(add-hook 'compilation-start-hook 'compilation-make-locals)
```

but without success.

The variable `compile-command` is not updated the to latest value when I interactively set a new command when doing `M-x compile`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
>      compile-command))
> ```

The latter `compile-command` is evaluated after `(make-local-variable 'compile-command)` so this should be a no-op -- you're making the variable buffer-local, and then setting the buffer-local value to whatever the buffer-local value already was.

---

I'm unsure what you are *wanting* to happen here, though.  What would "the latest value" be?

If it's the *global* value that you're wanting to copy to the buffer-local value, then you can obtain that with `(default-value 'compile-command)`

In the case where the buffer had a pre-existing buffer-local value, there may well be a difference between that and the global value.

Comment: So it should suffice to write `(make-local-variable 'compile-command)`, then?

Comment: I think that should work.

Comment: I've just noticed and fixed a mistake in the latter part of my answer -- I had stated that the `symbol-value` function gives the global value of a variable, when it's actually the `default-value` function which does this.